# How to grab data from object in child component and pass it to a method in the parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have been looking everywhere but I have not found a way. I only found how to pass data from parent to child in React. So that is why I am asking this question. I have a parent component which is a form and it takes input from whatever the user inputs. However, there is a field that it doesnt have access to in the parent component and is accessed in the method of the child component. That field is "priorityLevel" in the parent component which I have set to null(just waiting on the child component to provide that info). In the child component, I capture that "priorityLevel" data using a ref and storing that data in the "handleChange" method. It does log out the info that is selected. However, I need to pass that data to the parent component so that the parent component can see it and use it. Please see my code below. Thanks!

```
// Parent Component(TodoForm.js)

import React from "react";
import PrioritySelector from "./PrioritySelector";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class TodoForm extends React.Component {


    /*submit handler to grab input from the input references and store them
    in the "todoData" object. Then dispatches an action type and payload
    capturing the data. Then clears the input*/
    handleSubmit=(e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        const todoTitle = this.getTodoTitle.value;
        const description = this.getDescription.value;
        const priorityLevel = null;
        const todoData = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
            todoTitle,
            description,
            priorityLevel,
            editing: false
        }
        this.props.dispatch({type:"ADD_TODO", todoData })
        this.getTodoTitle.value = "";
        this.getDescription.value = "";
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getTodoTitle=input} placeholder="Enter Todo" required/>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getDescription=input} placeholder="Enter Description" required/>
                    <PrioritySelector />
                    <button>Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect()(TodoForm);



// Child Component(PrioritySelector.js)

import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class PrioritySelector extends React.Component  {

    componentDidMount() {
        $("#selector").show();
    }

    handleSelect =(e)=> {
        const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
        const priorityLevelData = {
            priorityLevel
        }
        console.log(priorityLevelData)

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <select onChange={this.handleSelect} ref={(option)=> this.getPriorityLevel = option} id="selector">
                        <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1">Low</option>
                        <option value="2">Medium</option>
                        <option value="3">High</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


const mapStateToProps=(state)=> {
    return {
        priorityLevel: state
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrioritySelector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TodoForm`:

```
state = {
    priorityLevel: {},
}
```

and

```
<PrioritySelector onSelect={priorityLevel => this.setState({ priorityLevel })} />
```

In `PrioritySelector`:

```
handleSelect =(e)=> {
    const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
    const priorityLevelData = {
        priorityLevel
    }
    this.props.onSelect(priorityLevelData)
}
```